# What is a quick way to know if an npm sub dependencies is upgradable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm looking for a way to find if a sub-dependencies is upgradable so I can upgrade that dependency in my consumer app.
If I do `npm list P3` I get something like this

```
P1@1.0.0
|__P2@1.0.0
|__|__P3@1.0.0
```

What I want to see is if P3 is upgradable from P2, ie if P2 lists dependencies P3 like so

```
{ // P2's package.json
   "dependencies": {
       "P3": "^1.0.0"
   }
}
```

What I want to see is that `^`so I don't have to dig into P2's package.json to look for it.
I know this looks like a quick thing to do but for a big dependencies list with really deep sub-dependencies, these are tedious to find. is there anything that I can run that will show me dependencies tree and version number with `^` or `~` ?
I know I can run npm view to see dependencies, but that still take too long, basically I'm just really lazy =]

Thanks